# div size increasing while drag and edit content

Tags: jquery, css

I simply created a contenteditable div.Its working fine what i expected but my problem is, I just animating the div in page load and then editing.after animating if i edit the content that div width is bigger than actual text.Check my fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/ux3k0t23/35/

**My css :**

```
#content {  width: 210mm;
        min-height: 297mm;
        padding: 20mm;
        margin: 10mm auto;
        border: 1px GREEN solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }

     @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;

    }
    @media print {
        html, body {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;

        }
        #content {
            margin: 0;
            border: initial;
            border-radius: initial;
            width: initial;
            min-height: initial;
            box-shadow: initial;
            background: initial;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    }
```

**My jsp :**

```
<div class='example' id="content">
<div id="editabledrag" contenteditable="false" style=" color:green; position: absolute;z-index:10000000;">Drag or double click and type!.</div>


</div>
```

Where i am doing mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You are animating the `bottom` at page load.
That way, css `bottom` remains set.

`draggable` changes the `top`. So when you drag, both `top` and `bottom` are set. Resulting in the div to be stretched to those values.

One workaround would be to animate only `top` at page load. Or after the animation resetting the `bottom` to `auto` and change the `top` accordingly. Like so:

```
$('#editabledrag').animate({left:'150px',bottom:'150px'},function(){
    $(this).css({"top":$(this).offset().top,"bottom":"auto"})
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ux3k0t23/36/